# Matlab - Change indexed window title

Tags: matlab, indexing, window, figure

I'm having some trouble changing the windowtitle on specific indexed windows (which are not created in this code). So I have three windows with standard names: figure 1, figure 2 and figure 3 which are indexed with figureid 1,2,3. I want to be able to change the windowtitle of the specific figureid but I can't get it to work.

I've tried to use gcf which works great, but even if I tell it to change figureid 1 it only changes the latest figureinput, figureid 3.

```
figureid = input('Figure-ID: ');

if ishandle(figureid)

newTitle=input('New windowtitle: ','s');
h(figureid) = plot_handles(figureid);
set(h(figureid), 'name', newTitle)
%set(gcf, 'name', newTitle)% <-- Only changes the last figureid input


else
disp('Invalid figure-ID!')

end
```

Comment: Have you tried using set(figureid, 'name', newTitle)?

Comment: Tried it now but it didn't work. Logically it shouldn't work since only writing figureid doesn't bring the handles in to the equation.

Comment: What is "plot_handles" and where do you get it from? You don't need to set h(figureid) = plot_handles(figureid) if you're only going to use it in the following line - just write plot_handles(figureid).

Comment: I had to add the index h(figureid) for it to work, I used plot_handles(figureid) alone at the beginning but it messed up the index. BTW; I got it all to work adding get(h(figureid),'Parent')

Comment: Then, `figureid` is the handle to the axes (`gca`), not the figure! Call it properly next time.